# Confusion with definition of Non-Centrality Parameter

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, f-test, non-central

So part of my research involves working with non-central distributions. One of the most important but at the moment more confusing ones is the non-central $\chi^2$, whose ncp is the one used in the definition of a non-central F distribution. However:

1. [StatisticsHowTo](https://www.statisticshowto.com/non-centrality-parameter-ncp/) has a great mini-summary on the subject of the ncp where $\lambda = \frac{n \sum_{i=1}^{n} \beta_{i}^2}{\sigma^2}$ is their most current definition (where they say the betas are the grand mean/ group means, probably $\mu_{i}$).
2. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution) defines it as $\lambda = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu_{i}^2$. [Purdue](https://www.stat.purdue.edu/%7Emlevins/docs/stat517/Lecture24_STAT517.pdf) defines it similarly as $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu_{i}^2}{\sigma^2}$. Neither have $n$ as a parameter.

Unsurprisingly I feel a bit lost. To make matters worse, I ran a simulation with three normal random variables, each with $\sigma^2=4$, $\mu_{1}=1$, $\mu_{2}=\mu_{3}=0$, and $n=30$ for all three samples. For the blue curve I used $\lambda=1$, since $\sum_{i=1}^3 \mu_{i}^2=1$. For the red curve I used the StatisticsHowTo definition with $\beta_{i}=\mu_{i}$. Neither fit. What am I misunderstanding about the right way to define the ncp?

[image]

```
#Code to simulate F statistics under the alternative

anova.test <- function(mu1,mu2,mu3,sigma,n1,n2,n3){
  s1 <- rnorm(n1,mu1,sigma) #Sampling 
  s2 <- rnorm(n2,mu2,sigma)
  s3 <- rnorm(n3,mu3,sigma)
  
  df <- data.frame('my_data'= c(s1,s2,s3), 'groups' = as.factor(c(rep(1,n1),rep(2,n2),rep(3,n3))))
  out <- anova(lm(my_data~groups,data = df))
  out$`F value`[1] #Outputs F statistic
}


set.seed(1333)

fsamp <- replicate(2500,anova.test(mu1=1,mu2=0,mu3=0,sigma = 2,n1=30,n2=30,n3=30)) #Replicating 2500 times
hist(fsamp,main = 'F-Statistics under alternatives', xlab = '',breaks = 100,freq = F)

curve(df(x,df1=2,df2=87,ncp=1),0,20,col = 'blue',add = T,lwd=2) #Uses wikipedia definition

curve(df(x,df1=2,df2=87,ncp=7.5),0,20,col = 'red',add = T,lwd=2) #uses statistics how to definition
```